# Is there any loss of data on installing Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

Will there be any loss of data stored on drives except C: drive if I install Kali Linux permanently ?

My PC is running Windows 10 .

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about replacing Windows 10 with Kali Linux then you are going to lose everything that is associated with Windows 10. There are other partitions on your disk so be careful not to delete all partitions.

My recommendation is to run Kali Linux in a Virtual Machine. This way you can have both Windows 10 and Kali Linux and run them side by side and they would just share resources and you would not lose any data.

I personally run Kali Linux using VirtualBox which is a virtual machine software. You download both VirtualBox and the Kali Linux ISO file and then you run the ISO file in VirtualBox.

Answer (score 2):

If you [**dual boot** Windows and Linux](http://docs.kali.org/installation/dual-boot-kali-with-windows), you will need to create an additional partition, but theoretically should lose no data. The *caveat* "theoretically" is because there is some danger that *partitioning* could completely wipe a disk... accidents *do* happen.

First make a disk image so that you can revert to a working OS. In Windows, there are a number of excellent free tools for this, such as [*Macrium Reflect Free*](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx) and *[DriveImage XML](https://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm)*.

Test out the version of Linux you plan to use by running it from a USB flash drive without installing anything on the HDD. If all goes well, then perform the installation.

Following this procedure has worked well for me for a number of installations, and I can run programs installed on the Windows partition using WINE. Better yet, shared data for programs such as Thunderbird, Firefox and LibreOffice can stay on the Windows partition even when running the native Linux version of the software. Note that Windows cannot share data well if its moved to a Linux ext*n* partition, though.

Comment: will i loss my movies stored on F: drive?

Comment: Is your F: drive USB-connected? Unplug it while you test Linux. Otherwise, back it up.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean replacing Windows to Linux, yes you lose all data in windows. If you really want both running in your PC I recommend dual boot or VM, you can search the process of it.

Comment: This is a repeat of information in other answers.  Answers are intended to each provide a solution substantially different from what has already been contributed.